# Resteasy @LinkResource constraint ExpressionLanguage PropertyNotFoundException

Tags: java, el, resteasy, hateoas

I'm using resteasy-links (2.3.7.Final) to enhance my resources with HATEOAS links.

When using a constraint for the @LinkResource to restrict its creation based on a property the BeanELResolver fails with a PropertyNotFoundException when the Type is passed in. The problem is that the RESTUtils of resteasy-links either pass in the entity or in the case of an ResourceFacade the type of the entity. Since the class of the entity obviously does not have the same properties as the entity itself this is bound to fail.

What I want to do is to only show the link if the entity has no endTime, which works perfectly well for the direct use case, but as soon as a ResourceFacade is used only the Type of the entity (DTO.class) is passed into the ELContext.
`@LinkResource(value = DTO.class, constraint = "${endTime == null}")`

I tried

1. `"${!(this instanceof java.lang.Class) && endTime == null}"`
2. `"${this.getClass() == 'DTO' && endTime == null}"`
3. `"${!this.toString().contains('class') && endTime == null}"`

but the 1. did not even compile and the second failed since Class does not have a getClass(). 3. works but seems rather hacky to me.

https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.7.Final/userguide/html/LinkHeader.html#8.2.8.%20Resource%20facades

Any better ideas?